# GraphQL and Binary format - ORM issue

Tags: orm, binary, graphql

We are exploring the use of GraphQL to add flexibility for our applications. Our back-end database is PostgreSQL v11.

We are loading a data model using hash keys with a binary format (256 bytes).
Today we understand that GraphQL in general does not directly support to serialize and return binary as-is. These keys are used to join tables and we see an issue here when using GraphQL.

None of the ORM that we investigated can support the binary data type.

Is it possible to use binary format in GraphQL?

Comment: encode as base64?

Comment: we are using sha2, 256 bits

Comment: it doesn't matter - every binary content can be base64 encoded to be passed as string ... it's used f.e. for passing [small] images from CMS

Comment: Thx, so we need to change the way we encode then? Cause as of now it is not working.

Comment: no, take your binary value and encode it using base64 - result is a string - send/read using graphql - decode on place you need (original) binary form   - like e-mail attachement is processed (binary>string (mail)>binary)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use binary in GraphQL? No, not directly. The output from a GraphQL query is JSON. There's no binary type in JSON.

But it seems like that's no what you're actually trying to do. You have binary keys in your existing data. Is your question whether it's possible to build a GraphQL API on top of this data? In that case the answer is yes.

But you would need to convert your binary IDs into strings (base64 for example) to use in the GraphQL responses. Plus you would need to implement all the GraphQL server if you don't find an existing GraphQL server which supports binary keys.